# Basic Loop through a matrix with pasting column names into result objects pt II

Tags: r

This is an edited version of 
[my initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145967/basic-loop-through-a-matrix-with-pasting-column-names-into-result-objects), which i obviously explained poorly, so ill try again.

I want to perform a function with every column of the dataframe, and name the resulting objects (here values of the class dist) according to the original dataframe and the colname:

```
library(vegan)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12),4,3), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))

Fun <-function(x){
  vegdist(decostand(x,"standardize",MARGIN=2), method="euclidean")
}
d1.A <- Fun(d1$A) # A being the colname of the first column of d1
d1.B <- Fun(d1$B)
d1.C <- Fun(d1$C)
```

This i want to do for more than 100 columns in my dataframe.

So, in short i want to apply my function to all columns of my dataframe and create result values with names that are made from the name of the original dataframe and a paste of the column name the function was working on.

Thank you very much!

Comment: From just looking at your code, `d1` and `d1.A` doesn't have any relation.  What is the use of `d1` here?

Comment: corrected it, sorry.

Comment: Do you want this to be stored as list or dataframe? or do you need separate `objects` ie. `d1.A, d1.B` etc. as shown here?

Comment: Do you remember http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978069/creating-a-matrix-from-a-list-of-pairwise-comparisons? The values that are created by Fun(x) will be put into the code you wrote for compiling all values by pattern="d1". So i dont need a list or matrix, just the values - ill collect them later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clutter your global environment with lots of objects, one option is `list2env` or you can use `assign` (Though, I would not recommend it).  Instead you can do all the operations/analysis by storing it in a `list` and later save/write to different files using `write.table` and `lapply`

```
 lst <- setNames(lapply(d1, Fun),
                paste("d1", colnames(d1), sep="."))
```

The above `list` could be used for most of the analysis. If you need as individual objects.

```
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
 #<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Now, you can get the individual objects by calling `d1.A`, `d1.B` etc.

```
  d1.A
  #        1         2         3
  #2 1.9838499                    
  #3 1.2754209 0.7084290          
  #4 2.2286961 0.2448462 0.9532752
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. For the next step: names<-ls(pattern="d1")
Cmb <- combn(names, 2)....can i apply ls to a the list "lst"? Because you are right: the workspace is quite cluttered.

Comment: @nouse This is one of the reasons why I suggested to do the operations inside the list.  Then you don't have to worry about doing `ls(pattern="d1")` stuff.  It is not clear what you wanted as next step. Is it in the link you shared?  I did go through the link.  I guess it is straightforward from Gavin Simpson's solution.  If you encounter any problems, let me know.

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160993/collect-values-by-common-patterns-from-a-list Thank you!

Comment: @nouse Looks like it got deleted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to create a number (equal to the number of columns of d1) of objects of class "dist".

If that is the case, you can do this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(d1))
{
  eval(parse(text=paste('d1.',colnames(d1)[i], "<-" ,"Fun(d1[,",i,"])", sep=""))) 
}
```

This evaluates in each iteration to:

```
 d1.V1 <- Fun(d1$V1)
 d1.V2 <- Fun(d1$V2)
 d1.V3 <- Fun(d1$V3)
```